# Pass python code as string over POST, and write it to file on server

Tags: python, angular, string

I have Python editor on my webpage, where the user enters python code. E.g.

```py
x = 1
if x==1:
    print("hello")
```

This code now is passed to the server through HTTP POST in an angular application, where the server will now store this code in a python script file.

However, the HTTP call removes the white spaces in the code above (e.g., the tab before print()).

`"x = 1\nif x==1:\nprint(\"hello\")"`

The python script therefore is not saved correctly to the file.

How can I make sure that the server receives the python code with all whitespaces?

Comment: Replacing tabs with \t might work

Comment: Using encoreURI before sending the code worked. Not sure if that is the best solution. So any validation or invalidation of this solution would help

Answer (score 0):

Convert the string to bytes before sending over. Below is the vanilla/pure javascript code to do that. Feel free to convert it to angular if you want to, but that's not necessary. It will still work if you mix angular and vanilla/pure js.

```
var str = "竜"; //or any char(s) that http might change
var bytes = [];
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; ++i) {
  var code = str.charCodeAt(i);
  bytes = bytes.concat([code & 0xff, code / 256 >>> 0]);
}
```

Then convert it back from bytes to string from your server.